# Poppler alternatives

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt4, poppler

Are out there some alternatives to the Poppler library?

My target is C++, in particular with the Qt 4 toolkit.

Comment: Is there any reason why Poppler doesn't suit your needs? All the popular Linux PDF readers use it.

Comment: Plus [it appears to be the method of choice](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq27-poppler.html) for displaying PDFs from within Qt...

Comment: Well, it's actually the GPL that bothers me. I primarily develop under the BSD license, and I'm uncomfortable with pure GPL projects...

Answer (score 0):

If you can compromise with few functionalities, You can live with XPdf. It is in GPLv2 but there is paid version too by http://www.glyphandcog.com/

I will recommend poppler over xpdf.

Comment: isn't poppler derived from xpdf. So could you not license xpdf and then use poppler?

Comment: Yes, it is. But they are separate projects at this point and may not be compatible in some of the implementations.